# Fire event after Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a project that works like a webproxy. Use it to make changes to other sites. (This part is important, I can only inject javascript code, but I can not change the code of the site itself.)

I'm trying to modify a website made in React and I can not do it. The site takes content through api and promises. So I have the problem:

**If I use:**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  document.getElementsByClassName ('content-class')[0].innerHTML="New Content";
});
```

Content does not exist yet and does not work

**If I use:**

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName ('content-class')[0].innerHTML="New Content";
}
```

It works after some time the content appeared.

**I Tried**

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content-class')[0];

content.addEventListener ('load', function() {

    document.getElementsByClassName('content-class')[0].innerHTML="New Content";

});
```

Unsuccessful too

How could I solve this? Is there any way to trigger an event after all the promises are finished?

Or detect that the element was created by the promise and trigger an event.

Comment: I had a similar problem once...curious to see what the answers will be. In my case, I solved by adding a timeout function that would retry to find the components in the page every X seconds...

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to tell when the promises are finished. but you could use a mutation observer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver to check what changes react makes to the DOM and make your changes accordingly

Comment: It sounds like perhaps the content that you're trying to modify is being added to the page by javascript and is not present in the actual HTML of the page.  There is NO standard way or any good way to know when all page Javascripts are done doing their thing because they can be doing all sorts of things that may take time to finish (like using Ajax calls).  You can either use DOM mutation observers to be advised when the page has been modified or starting at DOMContentLoaded, you can "poll" with a timer to look for when your `'content-class'` element exists.

Comment: @kevmc Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed. If you put in answer instead of comment.  I marked as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to trace promises that occur within the React app

However, modern browsers do have the mutation observer api [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which an be used to detect changes that the react app makes to the DOM